# Why Is This Rake Task Failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I have a simple Rake task that should kill all database connections then rebuild the app from scratch:

```
namespace :db do

  desc "Kill all Postgres connections"
  task kill: :environment do
    database_name = "#{ENV['APP_NAME']}_development"
    puts "killing database #{database_name} ..."
    sh = <<EOF
ps xa \
| grep postgres: \
| grep #{database_name} \
| grep -v grep \
| awk '{print $1}' \
| xargs kill
EOF
    puts `#{sh}`
  end

  desc "Rebuild and seed from scratch"
  task reup: [:kill, :drop, 'create:all', 'migrate', 'seed']
end
```

If I run each of these tasks in order from the command line, everything works great, but if I run this task, it always chokes on the migration task:

```
== 20141027190019 CreatePhotos: migrating =====================================
-- create_table(:photos)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "photos" already exists
: CREATE TABLE "photos" ("id" serial primary key, "dimensions" character varying(255), "media_item_id" integer, "created_at" timestamp, "updated_at" timestamp) /Users/pedr/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `async_exec'
```

So it appears that the database hasn't actually been dropped. What is extra strange is that this migration is the 12th migration, so it appears to be skipping the first 11.

Even if I manually drop the database, then confirm this by trying to run `rake db:migrate` (which tells me the database doesn't exist), then run `rake db:reup`, I get the same error, so it appears to think the database exists even though it doesn't. After this error occurs, if I run `rake db:migrate`, it successfully migrates from start to end.

**What could be going wrong?**

*Note: swapping `reset` for `migrate` works fine, but I need to rerun all migrations.*

Comment: `rake db:drop && rake db:create && rake db:migrate` is giving the same error? Could you perhaps have a duplicate migration file?

Comment: @SyedHumzaShah That runs fine, and as I mention in the question, running the rake tasks sequentially runs fine. There is no duplicate migration.

Comment: could be an environment issue. try specifying the environment somehow. either by passing an environment variable or (bad code smell) by invoking the tasks through `task reup: :environment do; %w{drop create:all migrate}.each{|t| Rake::Task["db:#{t}"].invoke}; end`

Comment: In other words, the migration operation might be carried on a database that isn't dropped yet. I think that by specifying the environment you would ensure that the same database is used throughout the tasks. Worth a shot, imo. :)